# Decomposition of a manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

As a kind of aside to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77175/decomposing-the-sphere-as-a-product) question, where one of the answers assumed that if $S^n=X \times Y$ then we can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are manifolds.

If we have a manifold $M$, such that $M$ is homeomorphic to $X \times Y$, then must $X$ and $Y$ be manifolds? The converse ($X,Y$ manifolds implies $X \times Y$ is a manifold) is certainly true. I'd like to think it is true, but I have seen enough strange topological behaviour to suggest this may not be true.

For this question take 'manifold' to mean a second countable Hausdorff space that is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, for some finite $n$.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this!  My intuition told me it was false, but maybe I'm just a cynic when it comes to spaces that aren't at least CW complexes.  Or does that make me an optimist?  I guess it all depends on your perspective  :o)

Comment: Juan, @Aaron: In case you missed it: there's a new [related thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83665/) on MO.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm by no means knowledgeable in this field and I haven't read the papers or books I mention below. I found these by digging in the literature and hope these pointers are useful.

---

The answer to your question is **no**.

1. The first example was given by R.H. Bing, *[The Cartesian Product of a Certain Nonmanifold and a Line is $E^4$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970322)*, Ann. of Math. (2) **70** (1959) 399–412. [MR107228](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=107228).

   Bing describes a topological space $B$ — in fact a quotient space of $\mathbb{R}^3$, sometimes called the [Dogbone space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogbone_space) — which is *not* a manifold and has the property that $B \times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$.
2. Modifying this construction and relying heavily on work of Andrews and Curtis, K.W. Kwun, *[Product of Euclidean Spaces Modulo an Arc](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970485)*, 
   Ann. of Math. (2) **79** (1964) 104–108, [MR159312](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=159312), produced product decompositions of $\mathbb{R}^n \cong X \times Y$ for $n \geq 6$ where neither $X$ nor $Y$ is a manifold.
3. Here are two freely available papers by A.J. Boals:

   - [Non-manifold factors of Euclidean spaces](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm68/fm68116.pdf), Fund. Math. **68** (1970), 159–177, [MR275396](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=275396) in which he describes classes $\Gamma_{m}$ and $\Gamma_{n}$ with the property that for any spaces $X \in \Gamma_{m}$ and $Y \in \Gamma_{n}$ we have $X \times Y \cong \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.
   - [Factors of $E^{n+3}$ with infinitely many bad points](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm79/fm79110.pdf), Fund. Math. **73** (1972), 95–99, [MR319201](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=319201).
4. Quoting C.D. Bass, *[Some products of topological spaces wich are manifolds](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1981-0601746-0)*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **81** (1981), 641–646, [MR601746](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=601746), Corollary 3 on page 645 “gives abundant examples of factorizations of certain manifolds into nonmanifold factors.”
5. A textbook covering these and many more topics:

   Daverman, Robert J., *[Decompositions of manifolds](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZfF3m7O8HpkC),*
   Pure and Applied Mathematics, 124, Academic Press, 1986, [MR872468](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=872468). (Reprinted by the AMS, 2007).

---

Here are two related MO-threads:

- [Is $\mathbb R^3$ the square of some topological space?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60375/is-r3-the-square-of-some-topological-space) (Richard Dore)
- [Square roots of $\mathbb R^{2n}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60395/) (Mariano Suárez-Alvarez)

**Added:** A further MO-thread was posted and answered a couple of hours ago:

- [Does Euclidean space have a compact factor?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83665/) (Richard Kent)

Comment: Thanks Theo! Nice detective work...I thought about searching through all of Bing's paper's. I had a feeling if it was not true he would have provided a counter example

Comment: @Juan (Qwirk): you're welcome. I wanted to look up this stuff for quite a while, so now I had the opportunity... Interesting stuff, but the details seem somewhat messy.

Comment: Great answer t.b.! You write "I'm by no means knowledgeable in this field" What would it be if you were:-)

Comment: Dear @Georges: Thank you, but yes, I meant it. I know little about geometric topology and the question at hand. I knew the Dogbone space and the two MO-questions, but not more.