# Are two spaces manifolds if their product is a manifold?

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decomposition of a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78055/decomposition-of-a-manifold)

For topological spaces $X,Y$, if their product space $X \times Y$ is a manifold, is it necessarily that $X,Y$ are manifolds?

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/169195/5363

Answer (score 11):

No. The [dogbone space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogbone_space) $D$ is a topological space that is not a manifold but $D \times \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^4$.